# Pands - Error: "No numeric types to aggregate" on numeric column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to groupby a dataframe by a string column (`b`) and get mean over the other column (`a`). When doing this I get an error I don't currently understand.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    1 : {'a':10,'b':'string1'},
    2 : {'a':20,'b':'string1'},
    3 : {'a':30,'b':'string1'},
    4 : {'a':1,'b':'string2'}
}).T
df.groupby('b')['a'].mean()
```

And I get the error:

`DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`

I have already tried to aggregate by 'hand' and it works, so I don't understand what is Pandas problem here

```
df_agg = {}

for g in df_grouped.groups:
  df_agg[g] = df_grouped.get_group(g)['a'].mean()\
df_agg
```

which return:  `{'string1': 20.0, 'string2': 1.0}` as I want.

Comment: The inital dataframe has columns of of mixed types (`dtype object`). After the transposition the `dtypes` of both columns are still `object`. You can convert `a` to `int` then use `mean`

Comment: Make the DataFrame like this instead: `pd.DataFrame({'a':[10,20,30,1],'b':['string1','string1','string1','string3']})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because `both columns are object type`.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 4 entries, 1 to 4
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   a       4 non-null      object
 1   b       4 non-null      object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 96.0+ bytes
```

**Solution**

We will need to convert `column a` to int so that it becomes `numeric type` and then apply mean over it.

```
df.a = df.a.astype(int)
df = df.groupby('b', as_index=False).mean()
```

**Output**

```
    b       a
0   string1 20
1   string2 1
```

**From Pandas doc**

Note: Any object column, also if it contains numerical values such as Decimal objects,is considered as a “nuisance” columns. They are excluded from aggregate functions automatically in groupby.
If you do wish to include decimal or object columns in an aggregation with other non-nuisance data types, you must do so explicitly.